# Convert each character of a string to a list of bits and append each list to a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.7

```
def string2bin(string):
    n=ord(string)
    bits1 = bin(n)[2:]
    bits2 = bits1.zfill(8)
    bits3 = list(bits2)
    bits4 = [ord(bit) - ord('0') for bit in bits3]
    return bits4
```

I am fairly new to python, and I have been asked to create a function that iterates over a string and converts each character to a list of bits, and then append that list to a list of lists
Every time I enter a string I get the error that I entered so many characters and it can only take one character.
Any suggestions?

Comment: A full error message may help. Does your code work for a single character?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
def string2bin(string):
    return [bin(ord(i)) for i in string]
```

Then:

```
print(string2bin('abcd'))
```

Is:

```
['0b1100001', '0b1100010', '0b1100011', '0b1100100']
```